# Eigenvalue decomposition in R

Tags: r, matrix, eigenvalue

Please excuse me for this simple question but how to do eigenvalue decomposition in R? The formula is A=VDV^(-1) where A is a square matrix and V is a matrix containing the eigenvectors of A and D is a diagonal matrix containing the distinct eigenvalues of A. Thanks for helping.

Below is a reproducible example:

```
##create the matrix
matrixa <- cbind(c(0.589, 0.202),c(0.033, 0.869))
##This is what I tried but it doesn't seem right
(eigen(matrixa)[[2]])*(eigen(matrixa)$values)*(solve(eigen(matrixa)[[2]]))
```

Comment: `*` is element-wise product, not matrix product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `%*%` + `diag`

```
with(
  eigen(matrixa),
  vectors %*% diag(values) %*% solve(vectors)
)
```

which gives

```
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] 0.589 0.033
[2,] 0.202 0.869
```

Comment: Great. Thank you@ThomaslsCoding!